# Disable 'PDF preview' or 'jump to PDF' option in LaTeXTools

Tags: sublime-text, latextools

I'm using LaTexTools in SublimeText and I'd like to disable the feature that automatically opens Evince (Linux user) after a successful compilation of my .tex file.

I can see there are options to keep the focus on SublimeText:

```
// Keep focus on Sublime Text after building (true) or switch to PDF viewer (false)
"keep_focus": true,
```

and to sync the position of the PDF:

```
// Sync PDF to current editor position after building (true) or not
"forward_sync": true,
```

but none of this prevent the PDF viewer from popping up every time I compile my file.

Is this possible?

Comment: Currently there's no option to do so, though I'm intending to add one in a future update. If you're happy editing the Python files, the relevant code is near the bottom of `makePDF.py` in your local package, but if you make a change there, it will be clobbered by the next release.

Comment: Thank you @ig0774, would you like to change your comment to an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there's no option to do so, though I'm intending to add one in a future update. If you're happy editing the Python files, the relevant code is near the bottom of `makePDF.py` in your local package, but if you make a change there, it will be clobbered by the next release.

Comment: Has this option has been implemented yet? I couldn't see it on the issues page.

Comment: Yes. It's done via the `open_pdf_on_build` setting.

Comment: Great! You should update your answer. (I was looking for the answer today and found this answer.)